# custom the x and y axis of webgl surface-plot in javascript

Tags: javascript, plot, axis, surface

I am working on a 3D Surface Plot in JavaScript created by Greg Ross. Everything is working well except that I cannot control axis tick labels, limits, and axes tick locations. My final goal is to have logarithmic scale on x and y axes and for that I need to control the distance between the tick labels and the origin for x and y axes.

But In my case I can only choose the axis labels:

```
// WeKno
            var canvas_height = ComputedStyleValue('surfacePlotDiv', 'height');
            var canvas_width = ComputedStyleValue('surfacePlotDiv', 'width');

            var surfacePlot;
            var data, data2, options, basicPlotOptions, glOptions, animated, plot1, plot2, values, values2;

            var numRows = 19;
            var numCols = 20;

            var tooltipStrings = new Array();
            var tooltipStrings2 = new Array();

            function setUp(){

                values = new Array();


                data = {
                    nRows: numRows,
                    nCols: numCols,
                    formattedValues: values
                };

                surfacePlot = new SurfacePlot(document.getElementById("surfacePlotDiv"));

                // Don't fill polygons in IE < v9. It's too slow.
                var fillPly = true;

                // Define a colour gradient.
                var colour1 = {
                    red: 0,
                    green: 0,
                    blue: 255
                };
                var colour2 = {
                    red: 0,
                    green: 255,
                    blue: 255
                };
                var colour3 = {
                    red: 0,
                    green: 255,
                    blue: 0
                };
                var colour4 = {
                    red: 255,
                    green: 255,
                    blue: 0
                };
                var colour5 = {
                    red: 255,
                    green: 0,
                    blue: 0
                };
                var colours = [colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4, colour5];

                // Axis labels.
                var xAxisHeader = "F";
                var yAxisHeader = "C";
                var zAxisHeader = "Cost [$]";

                var renderDataPoints = false;
                var background = '#ffffff';
                var axisForeColour = '#000000';
                var hideFloorPolygons = true;

                var chartOrigin = {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                };

                // Options for the basic canvas plot.
                basicPlotOptions = {
                    fillPolygons: fillPly,
                    tooltips: tooltipStrings,
                    renderPoints: renderDataPoints
                }

                // Options for the webGL plot.
                var xLabels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
                var yLabels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
                //var zLabels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

                // These labels are used when autoCalcZScale is false;
                glOptions = {
                    xLabels: xLabels,
                    yLabels: yLabels,
                    chkControlId: "allowWebGL",
                    autoCalcZScale: true,
                    animate: true
                };

                // Options common to both types of plot.
                options = {
                    xPos: 0,
                    yPos: 0,
                    width: canvas_width,
                    height: canvas_height,
                    colourGradient: colours,
                    xTitle: xAxisHeader,
                    yTitle: yAxisHeader,
                    zTitle: zAxisHeader,
                    backColour: background,
                    axisTextColour: axisForeColour,
                    hideFlatMinPolygons: hideFloorPolygons,
                    origin: chartOrigin
                };

                newplot();

                coordinateCharts();
            }

            function coordinateCharts(){
                // Link the two charts for rotation.

                plot1 = surfacePlot.getChart();

                if (!plot1 || !plot2) 
                    return;

                plot1.otherPlots = [plot2];
                plot2.otherPlots = [plot1];
            }

            setUp();

            function toggleChart(chkbox){
                surfacePlot.draw(data, options, basicPlotOptions, glOptions);
                surfacePlot2.draw(data2, options, basicPlotOptions2, glOptions2);

                coordinateCharts();
            }

            // ================== parser, evaluator ========================== WeKno

            function Demoparse(valueArray, toolTips){
                var idx = 0;
                var dataCF = generateDataCF();
                //var max = maxValue(dataCF);
                for (var x = 0; x < 19; x++) {

                    valueArray[x] = new Array();

                    for (var y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
                    var temp = dataCF[x][y];
                        valueArray[x][y] = temp;

                        toolTips[idx] = "x:" + x + ", y:" + y + " = " + 1;
                        idx++;

                    }

                }

            }

            function newplot(){


                    Demoparse(values, tooltipStrings);
                    surfacePlot.draw(data, options, basicPlotOptions, glOptions);

                coordinateCharts();

            }

            function ComputedStyleValue(ID, property)// WeKno
            {
                var e = document.getElementById(ID);
                return (window.getComputedStyle(e, null).getPropertyValue(property));
            }
```

Does anyone know how to control the position of the tick labels for x and y axes in order to build log scale axis?
Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

I send an email to Greg Ross and he responded:

"I'm afraid that the axes are not very flexible. Although it would be possible to achieve what you want by modifying the "renderAxisText" function. You'll see that it basically renders the xTitle, yTitle and zTitle at three points centred on each respective axis. All you need to to is pass in those x,y,zTitle variables as arrays, instead of strings, and then create a number of points along each axis according to each label in the array."

It means that it is possible to do it but I still don't know how to proceed exactly. Here is the code of the mentioned function:

```
this.renderAxisText = function(axes){
        var xLabelPoint = new Point3D(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
        var yLabelPoint = new Point3D(-0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
        var zLabelPoint = new Point3D(-0.5, 0.5, zTextPosition);

        var transformedxLabelPoint = transformation.ChangeObjectPoint(xLabelPoint);
        var transformedyLabelPoint = transformation.ChangeObjectPoint(yLabelPoint);
        var transformedzLabelPoint = transformation.ChangeObjectPoint(zLabelPoint);

        var xAxis = axes[0];
        var yAxis = axes[1];
        var zAxis = axes[2];

        canvasContext.fillStyle = this.axisTextColour;

        if (xAxis.distanceFromCamera > yAxis.distanceFromCamera) {
            var xAxisLabelPosX = transformedxLabelPoint.ax;
            var xAxisLabelPosY = transformedxLabelPoint.ay;
            canvasContext.fillText(xTitle, xAxisLabelPosX, xAxisLabelPosY);
        }

        if (xAxis.distanceFromCamera < yAxis.distanceFromCamera) {
            var yAxisLabelPosX = transformedyLabelPoint.ax;
            var yAxisLabelPosY = transformedyLabelPoint.ay;
            canvasContext.fillText(yTitle, yAxisLabelPosX, yAxisLabelPosY);
        }

        if (xAxis.distanceFromCamera < zAxis.distanceFromCamera) {
            var zAxisLabelPosX = transformedzLabelPoint.ax;
            var zAxisLabelPosY = transformedzLabelPoint.ay;
            canvasContext.fillText(zTitle, zAxisLabelPosX, zAxisLabelPosY);
        }
    };
```

If someone can be a little bit more precise it would really help me.

Thanks